# Will not load json file with json.load

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, discord.py, pycord

Working with my discord bot, and I'm trying to store a bunch of responses for a bunch of different commands in a json file. This command is just a set of dares, with the key "dare" and the value is a list full of different strings. When I use the `with open()` function, it registers it as a directory, and you can print the raw file but when you try to use `var = json.load` it just doesn't do anything. Any code after that line will not run.

I've used shell commands to go straight into that file and open it. That works completely fine. The file prints out normally.

```
    @commands.command()
    async def dare(self, ctx):
        """Gives the user a dare to do"""
    
        with open("cogs/docs/json/responses.json") as f:
            print(-1)
            print(f)
            data = json.load(f)
            print(0)
            dares = data["dare"]
            print(1)
            selectedDare = random.choice(dares)

        await ctx.reply(selectedDare)
```

The code above only print to `-1` and `f`. Nothing past that. `f` simply prints the object. I've also tried `json.loads` and such, nothing works. JSON **is** properly installed. I'm completely lost.

All of the responses are stored in a list, and here's the one that is just for this command.

```json
// this is all the responses for the dares
    {
        "dare":[
            "Dare #1",
            "Dare #2",
            "Dare #3"
        ]
    }
```

My bot handles the error has a CommandError, but nothing further.

```
# if a command flags an error it handles it
@client.event
async def on_command_error(ctx, error):
    """Handles errors"""

    if isinstance(error, commands.CommandError):
        print("CommandError found")
        return
```

Comment: Do you have a typo? Your code has: `dares = data["dares"]`, but you posted some `json` with: `{ "dare":[ ... ] }`

Comment: Ah, that is a typo thank you, but as said in the post the code doesn't even get down there. I also edited the json file to be 3 strings instead of the original 40+, so I might have forgot the `s` on the end..

Comment: Perhaps the `json.load()` causes an exception. Is it caught somewhere else and ignored?

Comment: ...part of the point of requesting a [mre] is so we can catch things like the above-referenced exception handling without needing to play 20 Questions.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy That is the entire piece of code that runs. Nothing else is connected that is why that's all that is posted.

Comment: ...the code included in the question should be the shortest possible thing that can cause the exact error being asked about when run without any changes at all. This code very much causes different errors when run without changes (no `import`s, no class the method is part of, etc etc).

Comment: What happens exactly when your code reach `data = json.load(f)` ? If there is an error, an exception will be raised.
Do you have, by any chance, somewhere in your code a cog-wide or bot-wide `on_command_error` or `on_error` function defined ? Maybe the exception is caught in one of those functions defined by you and ignored (not reraised)

Comment: @NathanMarotte Yes! Everything that causes an error actually has it's own custom message to notify when an error has been raised except `CommandError`. I just had a dummy print statement for it and it actually raises that specific error.  I don't exactly understand how I'd go about fixing the command off this though.

Comment: @goose.mp4 could you please include your code for this/those 2 functions then ? Also I published an answer, I'll edit it to match your specific case when I see the code :D

Comment: @NathanMarotte Sure, I'll edit my post to provide the error handling I have for my bot (just the CommandError part)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in comments, the issue comes from the author's defining a `on_command_error` or `on_error` function ( https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=on_command_error#discord.ext.commands.Bot.on_command_error )

Which will be called with the exception/error when it is raised anywhere in the bot/cog.

-> There should always be a default case for that defined function, for example if you write a few `if isinstance(e, SomeException): ...`, you will need a `else: raise e` or `else: super().on_command_error(e)` to make sure the default case is handled further, in case of an exception you didn't plan or that you don't need to worry about in your bot/cog

You could change your function to this

```
# if a command flags an error it handles it
@client.event
async def on_command_error(ctx, error):
    """Handles errors"""

    if isinstance(error, commands.CommandError):
        print("CommandError found")
        return
    super().on_command_error(ctx, error)
```

or this

```
# if a command flags an error it handles it
@client.event
async def on_command_error(ctx, error):
    """Handles errors"""

    if isinstance(error, commands.CommandError):
        print("CommandError found")
        return
    raise error
```

But I think the best approach would be

```
# if a command flags an error it handles it
@client.event
async def on_command_error(ctx, error):
    """Handles errors"""

    if isinstance(error, commands.CommandError):
        print("CommandError found")
    else:
        super().on_command_error(ctx, error)
```

and when adding other condition, for example other errors, you will have to use `elif`

Comment: How exactly would you add the `super().on_command_error(e)`?

Comment: Right after your `print("CommandError found") return`, so that it is executed in case the condition is false, I'll edit my answer

Comment: This error appears
`Ignoring exception in on_command_error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 343, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "main.py", line 210, in on_command_error
    super().on_command_error(ctx, error)
RuntimeError: super(): __class__ cell not found`

Comment: Then I think you can't super() there, but re-raising the error always work, so try the solution with `raise error`, your traceback will be longer but it will be accurate

Comment: Oh my gosh thank you so much. The comments where bugging out in the json file and expecting values because apparently JSON doesn't except comments. Thank you.

Comment: If you want something that's like JSON but with comments, think about YAML. (Yes, some YAML doesn't look like JSON at all, but all JSON is valid YAML, so you can just swap out the json module for a YAML parser and there you are)